# Ajax datatable is not inserting

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am studying about ajax datatabl. My AJAX datatable insert is not working. It has no error on console or whatsoever. It's just whenever I am inserting, the datatable is just refreshing. Is there anything that I missed? I have provided my codes below. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

This is the result whenever i'm adding. But it's not adding on database or whatsoever. [image]

**Views:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
                <br/>  
                <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>  
                <br /><br />  
                <table id="user_datas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
                     <thead>  
                          <tr>  
                         
                           <th width="35%">Name</th>  
                           <th width="35%">Email</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Edit</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     </thead>  
                </table>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >  
                <div class="modal-content">  
                     <div class="modal-header">  
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="modal-body">  
                      
                          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          
                          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                            
                     
                     
<!--                           <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />   -->
<!--                           <span id="user_uploaded_image"></span>   -->
                     </div>  
                     <div class="modal-footer">  
                          <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />  
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </form>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add_button').click(function(){  
           $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
           $('.modal-title').text("Add User");  
           $('#action').val("Add");  
 
      })  
      var dataTable = $('#user_datas').DataTable({  
           "processing":true,  
           "serverSide":true,  
           "order":[],  
           "ajax":{  
                url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'profile/fetch_user'; ?>",  
                type:"POST"  
           },  
           "columnDefs":[  
                {  
                     "targets":[0, 3, 3],  
                     "orderable":false,  
                },  
           ],  
      });  
      $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
           var name = $('#name').val();  
           var email = $('#email').val();   
           
          
     
     if(name != '' && email != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'profile/user_action'?>",  
                     method:'POST',  
                     data:new FormData(this),  
                     contentType:false,  
                     processData:false,  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                     console.log(name);
                     console.log(email);
                      
                          alert(data);  
                          $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#userModal').modal('hide');  
                          dataTable.ajax.reload();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                alert("Fields are Required");  
           }  
      });  
      }); 
 
  
 </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
function fetch_user(){
            $this->load->model("profiles");
            $fetch_data = $this->profiles->make_datatables();
            $data = array();
            foreach($fetch_data as $row)
            {
                $sub_array = array();

                $sub_array[] = $row->name;
                $sub_array[] = $row->email;
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
                $data[] = $sub_array;
            }
            $output = array(
                "draw"                    =>     intval(isset($_POST["action"] )),
                "recordsTotal"            =>     $this->profiles->get_all_data(),
                "recordsFiltered"         =>     $this->profiles->get_filtered_data(),
                "data"                    =>     $data
            );
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
        function user_action(){
            if(isset($_POST["action"])){
                if($_POST["action"] == "Add")
                {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        'name'          =>     $this->input->post('name'),
                        'email'           =>     $this->input->post("email.")

                    );
                    $this->load->model('profiles');
                    $this->profiles->insert_crud($insert_data);
                    echo 'Data Inserted';
                }
            }

        function fetch_single_user()
        {
            $output = array();
            $this->load->model("profiles");
            $data = $this->profiles->fetch_single_user($_POST["user_id"]);
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                $output['name'] = $row->name;
                $output['email'] = $row->email;
               
            }
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
}
```

Model:

```
var $table = "userss";
    var $select_column = array("id", "name", "email");
    var $order_column = array(null, "name", "email", null, null);
    function make_query()
    {
        $this->db->select($this->select_column);
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
            $this->db->like("name", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("email", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
        }
        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        }
    }
    function make_datatables(){
        $this->make_query();
        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    function get_filtered_data(){
        $this->make_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    function get_all_data()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
    function insert_crud()
    {
        $this->db->insert('userss', $data);
    }
```

Comment: did you look into the network tab of your browser?

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. Yes, it produces these outputs.

https://prnt.sc/10uqbu0

Answer (score 0):

What is your database structure? Is the table called userss or users?

```
$this->db->insert('userss', $data); <--Possible typo?
```

You likely will need to use the inspect feature of your browser and look at any responses under the network tab to see any errors.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. I'm doing a testing that's why it has double "s"
https://prnt.sc/10uqajo.

Comment: What is displayed under the response and preview tabs?